# How to perform bulk upload in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use bulk upload in angular2,i googled about it but still i am not clear about that .Can anyone please post me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this code implementation

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload files" multiple>

fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    let fileListLength = fileList.length;
    if(fileListLength > 0) {
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < fileListLength; i++) {
            formData.append("uploadFile[]", fileList[i]);
        }
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i extract data in the excel sheet from client side.

Comment: sorry @Arnold, I didn't know about extract data in the excel, need to analyze. Raise a new question to get help